# Are there meaningful differences in meaning and usability between 'calculare' and 'computare'?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, history

Is there any meaningful difference, from the point of view of classical philology (not from the point of view of contemporary usages and dictionaries which more or less seem to consider them synonyms) in the meaning/register/usage of the Latin verbs **calculare** and **computare**?